# Only copy certain columns

Tags: excel, vba

i have a VBA macro to copy certain columns and at the same time clear some of them. Now my problem is that I have a weekly update list, so I have all calendar weeks listed and I need to clear 2 columns out of 5 in each week. Now I don't know if I have to type down every single column manually in the macro or if there is a smarter way to solve it.

[The sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xorw.png)
As seen in picture one, in each week I need the columns where Question and Comment are, to be deleted when I copy that row.

in the following my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
  Cancel = True
  Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
  Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow
  Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Font.Bold = False
  Target.Offset(1).Columns("L").Font.Bold = True
  Target.Offset(1).Columns("A:N").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
  Target.Offset(1).Columns("R:FZ").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
  Target.Offset(1).Columns("B:F").ClearContents
  Target.Offset(1).Columns("K:M").ClearContents 
Else

End If   
End Sub
```

EDIT:

Another possibility would also be to only copy the format of the columns instead of clearing them. is that possible?

Comment: Is the place you double click directly in the week you're trying to clean up? If it is, you can use the offset to select the correct column instead of forcing a column on the function like so `Target.Offset(*no of rows*,*no of columns*.Entirecolumn.Clearcontents`

Comment: I gather you have 6 columns per week. Is that always the case? Does the number of weeks grow or is that fixed? I guess you just want to clear certain columns in the new row, which is initially copied from the preceding row. The code seems to be clearing more than two columns in the new row - B:F is 5 cols and K:M is 3 cols. In which column does the first week begin? Do you want to clear the same two columns (Question and Comment) for every week in the new row?

Comment: The place i double click is in Column A. It is the Project Number.
The cleanup shall be done for every week.
Each week has 6 Columns.
Comment, Question, FG and Timetac shall be cleared. So all 4 neighbouring columns.
The columns in the code e.g. B:F are "Fixed" Data independent from the weeks.

Comment: In which column does the first week begin - is that Col G or Col N or maybe Col R? How many weeks are there - is that fixed or does it grow week by week? If you want to clear 4 columns, why do you say in the main question that you want to clear only 2 columns?

Comment: FG and Timetac are not neighbouring columns - there is a column between them. So, do you want that column to be cleared too, that means 5 neighbouring columns?

Comment: Beginns in Column R. the sheet has Weeks covered till the end of the Year. i want the option to adapt it by myself int he code, if 2,4 or 5 columns shall be cleared. thats yet to be cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code which I think should achieve OP's objectives, based on what has been requested so far, though I am not sure I have fully understood.

For the purposes of coding, I have made these assumptions, subject to confirmation from OP:

- The first column of the first week is Col R, the second week Col X, third week col AD, etc.
- There are 6 columns per week for every week.
- There are 27 weeks altogether, covering column R for week 1 col 1 through to col FW for week 27 col 6.
- Five columns out of six for each week (of the new row only) will be cleared (that is, all columns except the first column of each week).

If any of these assumptions is wrong the code will need to be adjusted accordingly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    '// Check if double-click is in first column
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        '// Get first cell of the selection, we only want to add one row
        Target = Target.Cells(1, 1)
        Cancel = True

        '// Insert a new row under the row that was clicked
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

        '// Set a variable to point to the new row
        Dim newRow As Range
        Set newRow = Target.Offset(1).EntireRow

        '// Copy the whole of the clicked row to the new row
        Target.EntireRow.Copy newRow.EntireRow

        '// Format the new row and clear some columns first
        With newRow
            .EntireRow.Font.Bold = False
            .Columns("L").Font.Bold = True
            .Columns("A:N").Interior.Color = 10086143
            .Columns("R:FZ").Interior.Color = 10086143
            .Columns("B:F").ClearContents
            .Columns("K:M").ClearContents

            '// Get the range of the first week, cols R to W from the newRow
            Dim rWeek As Range
            Set rWeek = .Range("R1:W1")

            '// Now loop round 27 times to clear specific cols in each week
            Dim iWeek As Integer
            For iWeek = 1 To 27

                '// Clear contents from the second to sixth column of the week (B:F)
                rWeek.Range("B1:F1").ClearContents

                '// Now move the week to the next week by offsetting by the
                '// number of cols in the week (in this case 6 cols)
                Set rWeek = rWeek.Offset(0, rWeek.Columns.Count)
            Next iWeek
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charme  after some minor changed :) Kudos to you.

Answer (score 0):

"Smarter" is subjective but this could be done by defining a collection of columns you want to delete and loop over the range of column headers.

Here a small example snippet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyForCollection()

    Dim colToClear As New Collection
    Dim rngColumnHeaders As Range
    Dim varHeader As Range

    Dim intHeaderRow As Integer

    ' Define column names that need clearing
    colToClear.Add "A"
    colToClear.Add "B"

    ' Set row containing column headers
    intHeaderRow = 1

    ' Define column header range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataTable")
        Set rngColumnHeaders = .Range(.Cells(intHeaderRow, 1), .Cells(intHeaderRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    ' Loop header cells and check for name
    For Each varHeader In rngColumnHeaders
        If HasValue(colToClear, varHeader.Value) Then
            varHeader.EntireColumn.ClearContents
        End If
    Next varHeader       
End Sub

Function HasValue(colValues As Collection, strValue As String)

    Dim varVal As Variant
    Dim booRes As Boolean

    booRes = False

    For Each varVal In colValues
        If varVal = strValue Then
            booRes = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next varVal

    HasValue = booRes
End Function
```

This can of course be adapted to include other operations such as copying, each operation requiring its own collection of column names.